# Can't bind MWArray.dll to F# Interactive

Tags: f#, matlab-deployment, f#-interactive

I generated a .Net Library using [MATLAB .Net Builder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/datasheets/pdf/matlab-builder-ne.pdf). I managed to use it without any problem in C#, but I am now trying to do some tests using a quick F# wrapper that I created in F# Interactive.

The thing is, I can't seem to be able to use the `MWArray` class in F# Interactive.

I managed to reference the DLL using the `#r` command, but I cannot find the `MathWorks` domain when using intellisense after the `open` command.

Furthermore, if I run my code, I get the following error when the flow encounters an `MWArray`:

> Binding session to 'C:\Program Files\mypath\bin\Debug\MWArray.dll'...

followed by

> error FS0193: internal error: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\mypath\bin\Debug\MWArray.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MWArray, Version=2.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e1d84a0da19db86f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'MWArray, Version=2.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e1d84a0da19db86f'
>   (...)   at .$FSI_0009.main@() in C:\Program Files\mypath\ScriptTest.fsx:line 49
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Stopped due to error

I really have no idea where this comes from and how to solve the problem.

Has anyone been successful in using MATLAB .Net Library from F#?

Have you got a suggestion to help me solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with MatLab and .NET interop, but have you checked the architecture? In other words, make sure you are not trying to load a 64-bit DLL into a 32-bit process or vice-versa. Also, if you are loading a managed assembly which makes P/Invoke calls to a native assembly, then that native DLL should be in the directory from which you current FSI session is running. You can both check and set this value via `CurrentDirectory` property of the `System.Environment` class.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about F#-interactive, but I have just managed to make a very basic F# 3.0 console application which uses the MWArray.dll and a matlab function which I compiled with the matlab NE builder...

```
open makesquare
open MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays
[<assembly: MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCROption("-nojit")>] 
do()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let stuff = new MLTestClass()
    let numArray = new MWNumericArray(5)
    let res = stuff.makesquare(1, numArray)
    let res_val = res.GetValue(0)
    printfn "%A" res_val
    System.Console.ReadKey()
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

The makesquare function, is just the simple function made in this tutorial
http://www.mathworks.se/help/dotnetbuilder/ug/create-a-net-component-from-matlab-code.html

For a similar solution in C# with .net 4.+:
[use .net 2.0 dll in .net 4.5 project (vshost crashes on debug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100113/use-net-2-0-dll-in-net-4-5-project-vshost-crashes-on-debug)