# use .net 2.0 dll in .net 4.5 project (vshost crashes on debug)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, matlab

I am trying to use a dll file created from matlab with the dotnetbuilder (http://www.mathworks.se/help/dotnetbuilder/ug/create-a-net-component-from-matlab-code.html)..

In order to use the dll, I have to add a refference to a matlab dll called 'MWArray.dll' (http://www.mathworks.se/help/dotnetbuilder/ug/integrate-your-net-component-in-a-c-application.html), and sadly this dll only seem to be available for .net 2.0.

The only way I've been able to make a simple console application work with the dll I created from matlab, was by doing following:

- target the dll for .net 2.0 when building it in matlab with
  dotnetbuilder.
- change the version of .net used in my console
  application to version 2.0

If I don't do this, the console application will crash vshost.exe when I try to run the project.

I wish to be able to use .net 4.+ features, so configuring the project to use .net 2.0 is not acceptable.. And when I get this simple console application running with at least .net 4.0, I will try to get it working in an F# 3.0 application as well.

My program looks like this:

```
...
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using makesquare;

namespace Matlabski
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var stuff = new makesquare.MLTestClass();
                var res = stuff.makesquare(1, 3);
                Console.WriteLine(res[0]);
                Console.WriteLine("sdfsdf");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

and I have attempted to edit the app.config file to be able to handle both .net 2 and 4:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

But it doesn't work..

**Is it possible to setup the project such that I can use both .net 2.0 and 4.5, and will this make my project work?? or do I have to do something else to use this annoying .net 2.0 dll..?**

I am using:

- VS2013
- MATLAB R2013b (64bit)

Comment: Why is it crashing vshost though?  Have you attached a debugger and seen what the exception is?  It may be a very simple thing to fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved the problem!

I compiled my matlab function targeting .net 4...
and then I added

```
[assembly: MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCROption("-nojit")]
```

to the code..

the resulting code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using makesquare;
[assembly: MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCROption("-nojit")] 

namespace Matlabski
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                MLTestClass stuff = new MLTestClass();
                object[] res = stuff.makesquare(1, 3);
                Console.WriteLine(res[0].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("sdfsdf");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

the app.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

however, the app.config doesn't seem to be needed...

Comment: Thank you very much. I was struggling with this same issue for long time and ended up creating a separate project for .NET 2.0 where WMArray was used.

How did you find information about this special assembly option -nojit ?